# How to make input fit on a layer of div width with css

Tags: html, css

I create a webpage like following

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      border: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .wrapper {
      padding: 50px 50px;
    }
    
    .inp {
      display: block;
      padding: 6px 12px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 44px;
      font-size: 14px;
      background-color: #f00;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" class="inp" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And now, the input width is out of the row, please look at following image

[image: demo image]

I know the line `padding: 6px 12px;` cause this, and if I don't want to remove `padding: 6px 12px;` how can I fix this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `box-sizing:border-box` in input:

```
  .inp {
      display: block;
      padding: 6px 12px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 44px;
      font-size: 14px;
      background-color: #f00;
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

**Demo:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 50px 50px;
}

.inp {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #f00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" class="inp" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

By default in the CSS box model, the width and height you assign to an element is applied only to the element's content box. If the element has any border or padding, this is then added to the width and height to arrive at the size of the box that's rendered on the screen. This means that when you set width and height, you have to adjust the value you give to allow for any border or padding that may be added.
More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Answer (score 1):

Use `box-sizing: border-box`, because the padding is added on top of the 100% width, so you get 100% + 12px of horizontal dimension. See proof-of-concept below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 50px 50px;
}

.inp {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #f00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" class="inp" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
```